# Hawking radiation and relativity

Tags: special-relativity, black-holes, hawking-radiation, evaporation

Suppose that there is a black hole with such a mass (e.g. one thousand ton), so that it would evaporate (at rest, and no inflow of material or radiation) in ~80 seconds.
If it is somehow accelerated up to (or the conditions under which it appears forces it to move at)  **99.9% of light-speed**, so that the Lorentz factor is ~22.37, would the black hole evaporate the same time (80 sec), or multiplied by Lorentz factor (~1790 sec) (for someone who is not moving)?

In other words, would the ultrarelativistic speed of the micro-black hole make its decay time longer than usual (for an observer who is at rest)?
Or the Hawking radiation time is independent on the speed of the object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Time dilation is universal, it does not depend on the method used to measure time. So yes, a black hole moving at 99.9% of light speed would need much more time to evaporate.